# Python: Read Cell from Excel with Coordinates

Tags: python, excel, cell, xlrd, xlwt

What I try to do here is to *read* some values out of an excel sheet. I would like to do it with coordinates (X,Y) and not the classical "A1","A2" etc approach.
In the same code I am also writing sone numbers in the excel sheet. That works fine.
By running this code I get this error:

> AttributeError: 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'cell'

```
book = xlrd.open_workbook_xls("abc.xls", formatting_info=True)
wb = copy(book)
sh = wb.get_sheet(0)
a = 1

for i in range(10):
    cell1 = sh.cell(0,1)
    print(cell1)

    sh.write(i,0, a)
    print(a)
    a = a+1
wb.save("abc.xls")
```

Is there a way to *read* from excel? And print the cell, or do further calculations?

Answer (score 1):

Use `cell_value` with `rowx` and `colx` arguments, instead of `cell`. The [example](https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd) on the GitHub landing page mentions this. Here is the relevant excerpt from the example:

> `print("Cell D30 is {0}".format(sh.cell_value(rowx=29, colx=3)))`